# Error compiling with Poco in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, poco-libraries

I am working on a project at work that includes a project that was built using the Poco library. When I attempt to compile the project, XCode gives me many errors related to the STL. After some searching around on the internet, I was able to deduce that including Poco can be the cause of this, but no answers on how to fix this problem.

Here are the errors:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:298:9: No member named 'memmove' in namespace 'std'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:321:7: Use of undeclared identifier 'ostreambuf_iterator'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:321:27: '_CharT' does not refer to a value
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:321:35: Expected unqualified-id
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:326:9: Use of undeclared identifier 'ostreambuf_iterator'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:326:29: '_CharT' does not refer to a value
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:326:37: Expected unqualified-id
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:331:5: Variable '__copy_aux' declared as a template
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:331:16: Use of undeclared identifier 'istreambuf_iterator'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:331:36: '_CharT' does not refer to a value
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:331:43: Expected expression
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:407:18: Use of undeclared identifier 'ostreambuf_iterator'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:407:38: '_CharT' does not refer to a value
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:407:46: Expected unqualified-id
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:446:9: No member named 'memmove' in namespace 'std'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:600:10: No member named 'memset' in namespace 'std'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:608:10: No member named 'memset' in namespace 'std'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:616:10: No member named 'memset' in namespace 'std'
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:908:31: No member named 'memcmp' in namespace 'std'

Any help would be greatly appreciate. I should note that I am not calling the Poco library directly, but some of the code from the other project makes reference to it.

Comment: Did you try reordering your #include and #import directives?  (#import any apple stuff FIRST?)

Comment: To update this issue, for some reason XCode insisted on using an outdated compiler. I was able to get the command line version of clang++ working with flags, so this issue is resolved.